# I created a REST Api flow to make outbound calls but I can't run it with python

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

So i created a REST Api flow on stwilio studio the thing is that i dont know how to run it to start making calls.

I have a python script to make calls and leave a message. Do I have to change this script to run it with the flow? how am i supposed to make it work. I cant find any documentation on this.

The idea is to call a list of contacts and play a pre-recorded audio if they press 1 the call will be forwarded to our office, if they say something the app will record a voicemail.

This is the python script to make calls:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import keys

client = Client(keys.account_sid, keys.auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
    url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH498d38b38ad2faa90dfec86ec1fd43d0",
    to=keys.target_number,
    from_=keys.twilio_number
)

print(call.sid)
```

[This is the REST Api flow I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P66LC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code triggers a normal call with TwiML instructions. Are you planning to trigger a Studio flow execution from Python code? If so, this code will help you:

```py
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
import os
from twilio.rest import Client


# Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

execution = client.studio \
                  .v2 \
                  .flows('FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
                  .executions \
                  .create(to='+15558675310', from_='+15017122661')

print(execution.sid)
```

> [Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/execution)